# How to download a Java applet from webpage?

Tags: java, class, applet, view-source

I'm trying to figure out a way to download this one java class from a programming site, but I seem to be getting error when I try accessing the link after I viewed the source? Can anyone show me how to do this correctly? Or be willing to do a step by step on how I would operate in doing this task?

The applet I'm trying to download is from this site:

http://problets.org/user/services/decode.html

Comment: an applet is byte code

Comment: I could not find a way to download either the class file or the JAR.  Maybe you can contact the site administrator for help?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I have solved it. It was the archive="Decoder.jar". I just changed decode.html, to decoder.jar and it worked.

Thanks for the help anyways